# switching off all the emission & bounce light in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

can anybody help me out in knowing how to switch off all the emission & bounce light in Cycles.

Comment: As @MahmoodulHassan said you should do that, but whats the reason, why you are doing it..

Answer (score 1):

Go to the node editor, remove emission and glossy nodes. 
You can find node editor on bottom left corner.